# API Rest Sharepoint - updating metadata while creating a file

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint-online

I am using a POST request to create a file in a Sharepoint's libray which uses metadata (columns on the Sharepoint site).

I get a status code 200, the file is created. That's fine. But metadata are not updated...

Here after is a parte of the code I'm using:

```
    endpoint_url = site_url + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('test')/Files/add(url='facture2.pdf',overwrite=true)" 

    # requête pour récupérer les fichiers dans la bibliothèque test
    #endpoint_url = site_url + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('test')/Files" 
       
 
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + bearer,
               "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
    data = file_content
    
    metadata = {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.TestListItem" },
    "Client": "Nom du client",
    "Date_x0020_de_x0020_facturation": "2023-04-14T00:00:00Z"
}
    
    # Envoi de la requête HTTP de dépôt du fichier facture
    response = requests.post(endpoint_url, headers=headers, data=data, params=metadata)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        messages.success(request, 'POST Facture OK:'+ str(response.content))
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Echec POST facture : " + str(response.content) )
```

and a snapshot of the Sharepoint library